# Is there a software license that says anyone can do what they want with it except sell it or sell modified versions of it?

Tags: licensing, gpl

From what I can tell GPL lets folks modify your code and sell it and MIT lets them do whatever they want.

I plan on charging for my application. I am okay if someone wants to tweak it and use it for their own or make it available for others.

But I don't want them to take my code and charge people, or tweak my code and charge for the tweaked code.

Is there a license good for this?